# jQuery iterating over an Object(JSON)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

The JSON is:

```
{"Name":"bb", "age":"10"}
```

I searched a lot of in the Internet but most of the answers are for I know "Name" and "age" previously, so they reference like j.Name, j.age.

I am just wanting to do equivalent thing as, we don't know the keys inside the object, we want to iterate over all items and print out both KEY and VALUE(we don't know KEY previously). The for each statement is doing fine in Firefox but I found IE can't support for each loop...

Comment: What does your loop look like?

Comment: FYI, it's not "a json" or "an associative array" but "an object".

Comment: @TheifMaster technically, that is valid JSON :-)

Comment: yeah, but "iterating over json" makes no sense ;p

Comment: @pst - JSON is a text format. Though the object in the question likely start out as JSON.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `for...in` loop, like this:

```
var obj = {"Name":"bb", "age":"10"};
for(var key in obj) {
  if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key))
    alert("Key: " + key + "\nValue: " + obj[key]);
}
```

Or in jQuery the [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) if you need the closure, like this:

```
var obj = {"Name":"bb", "age":"10"};
$.each(obj, function(key, value) {
    alert("Key: " + key + "\nValue: " + value);
});
```

[You can test both versions here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/VTArq/).

Comment: If his object comes from JSON or an object literal he doesn't really need .hasOwnProperty - unless somebody messed with Object.prototype which [is a Bad Thing](http://erik.eae.net/archives/2005/06/06/22.13.54/)

Comment: @ThiefMaster - The latter *does* happen, why is why I prefer my code samples to be safe for *all* cases :)

Comment: @ThiefMaster - just curious, did you read the link you added? The *very* first line is "It is not seldom that you see people messing with `Object.prototype`"...

Comment: Prototype.js (read: mangling of all standard prototypes) forever \o/. Would up-vote, but am out :(

Comment: Nope, I didn't - but if prototype.js messes with Object.prototype it's probably a good reason to not use it... even though it's popular ;x

Comment: @ThiefMaster - I don't disagree at all, [even some of the Prototype core team members feel the same](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/) ...but saying "you shouldn't handle this" because it's a bad practice doesn't people aren't doing it, why *not* handle it when it's so cheap to do so?

Comment: @ThiefMaster - prototypejs doesn't mess with Object.prototype. From their docs: *"Extensions to the built-in Object object. Because it is dangerous and invasive to augment Object.prototype (i.e., add instance methods to objects), all these methods are static methods that take an Object as their first parameter."* They do augment other types as you saw in the link Nick provided.

Answer (score 1):

Without jQuery you would use a `for-in` loop

```
var person = {"Name":"bb", "age":"10"};

for(var attr in person) {
  alert('Attribute: '+attr);
  alert('Value: '+person[attr]);
}
```

... in jQuery:

```
var person = {"Name":"bb", "age":"10"};
$.each(person, function(attr, value) {
  alert('Attribute: '+attr);
  alert('Value: '+value);
});
```

Comment: You should also likely use `hasOwnProperty` (good in general when using `for(...in...)`) in case some fun person decorated the Object prototype.

Answer (score 1):

```
var json = {"Name":"bb", "age":"10"}
for ( var i in json ) {
    console.log( json[i] );
}
```

Comment: I'd not use `i` for a non-numeric loop variable - in a for..in loop over an object it contains a key, not a numeric index (even though the key could be numeric, but that's not the point).

Comment: You should also likely use `hasOwnProperty` (good in general when using `for(...in...)`) in case some fun person decorated the Object prototype.

Comment: @ThiefMaster while I do see your point, I consider `i` to be clearly the index in a loop, making the code more readable. Coding style in my opinion, really - neither is wrong.

Comment: @pst I should also use `try catch`, strict... Purpose of that code was to give a simple working example without any frills to render it immediatly understandable, not to make safe code ;)

Comment: @Razor - I have to agree that `i` is a bad name here, for exactly your comment, it's *not* the **index** in a loop , it's a **key** for the current object, `i` being `2` doesn't mean it's not the 40th key in the object, better to be safe and use a variable that doesn't imply it's an index IMO.

Comment: @Razor Why should one use try-catch? It adds nothing here (and would actually fuddle things) while `hasOwnProperty` does something very practical (if nothing else it gets around stupidly pedantic JSLint errors, which I don't agree with, but I digress... anyway, add a line, save headaches later).

Comment: @ThiefMaster Perhaps you are confusing JavaScript with Fortran: "Unless specified otherwise, all variables starting with letters I, J, K, L, M and N are default INTEGERs..." :-)